# How to invoke a class's default constructor whose one is provided by a ctor with all default paramters?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

It is said in C++ primer 5Th edition that a constructor that provides default arguments for all the parameters defines also default constructor:

```
class Point {
    public:
        //Point(); // no need to define it here.
        Point(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x_(x), y_(y){
            std::cout << "Point(int=0, int=0)" << std::endl;
        } // synthesize default constructor Point()
        int x_;
        int y_;
};

int main(){
    Point pt; // default ctor Point() or Point(int, int)?
    Point pt2 = Point(); // this won't compile?!
}
```

As you can see above I wanted for some reason to invoke the default constructor `Point()` not `Point(int, int)` but I get the latter not the default ctor?!

So is it possible to invoke the default constructor of a class provided by a constructor that provides default arguments for all the parameters? Thank you.

Comment: If you add a constructor that defaults all parameters, it *is* the default constructor.

Comment: @SidS: It won't compile if I do so for the fact that no more than one default constructor for a class is allowed.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to distinguish between the two ?

Comment: If you want both the default constructor and the other constructor then you need to get rid of the default parameters.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want "for some reason" to invoke a constructor `Point()` when there is another constructor that has default values for all arguments??    The rules of the language are quite clear -  if instantiating an object and providing no arguments (`Point pt` or `Point pt2 = Point()`) then both a constructor with no arguments (`Point()`) and one with all arguments defaulted (`Point(int x = 0, int y = 0)`) are equally good matches.   Hence your code is ambiguous (equally good matches, and no basis to prefer one over the other) and that prevents compilation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A class can have at most one default constructor. If the constructor that has argument is a default constructor, then there may not be a default constructor that does not take arguments. Otherwise invocation of the default constructor is ambiguous.

> So is it possible to invoke the default constructor of a class provided by a constructor that provides default arguments for all the parameters?

Well, yes. In that case the default constructor is the constructor that provides default arguments for all parameters. Example:

```
class Point {
    public:
        Point(int x = 0, int y = 0);
};

int main(){
    Point pt; // the default constructor Point(int,int) is invoked
}
```

Comment: I think it is legal to have multiple default constructors, if you never try to default-construct an object

Comment: @M.M Probably. That makes the beginning of my answer technically wrong, but I think it is easier for non-language-lawyers to understand.

Answer (score 8):

If you add a constructor that defaults all parameters, it *is* the default constructor.

If you want both, remove one or more of the default arguments.